# PHP Foreach Skip Results from Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to limit the amount of results that show in my foreach, I've got this so far:

```
    <?php $facilitiescounter = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($facilities as $data) { 
    if (++$facilitiescounter == 7) break; 
    echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; }?> 

    <a class="read-more-show hide" href="#">Show More</a> <span class="read-more-content">Show all other results from array <a class="read-more-hide hide" href="#">Show Less</a></span>
```

I have managed to limit it to the first 6 results, is it possible to do another foreach to get all the other results excluding the first six?

Or is there a better way of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: what about a simple for-loop?

Comment: Maybe try use [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `for` loop is more appropriate in this case, as we can determine begin and end easily

To the first six results:

```
for($i = 0, $t = min(6, count($facilities)); $i < $t; ++$i)
{
    $facilities[$i]->Name
    ....
```

The other ones:

```
for($i = 6, $t = count($facilities); $i < $t; ++$i)
{
    $facilities[$i]->Name
    ....
```

Note: added minimum verification in case `$facilities` has less than 6 elements. Thanks to @lanis

Comment: This answer is great... except $facilities has less than 6 items... so I would use min(6, count($facilities) in the for continue condition : `for($i = 0; $i < min(6, count($facilities)); ++$i)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use array_slice() http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-slice.php

```
$datas = array_slice($facilities, 0, 6); // First 6 items

foreach($datas as $data) {
    echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
}

$datas = array_slice($facilities, 6); // Items after 6

foreach($datas as $data) {
    echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it as a better way. Just get your $facilities array in some temporary array which is called $temp and then whenever your foreach loop is executing just remove that element from the $temp array. After that you just replace $facilities array with the $temp.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $facilitiescounter = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($facilities as $data) { 
if (++$facilitiescounter <= 7) break; 
echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; }?> 

<a class="read-more-show hide" href="#">Show More</a> <span class="read-more-content">Show all other results from array <a class="read-more-hide hide" href="#">Show Less</a></span>
```

i have changed the if condition only. it will give you proper result. try it!